# how can we invoke the function call() below ? to alert name

Tags: javascript

I've put the sample code but it seems it is not easy to make it alert name from two function above Name() and User()

```
function Name(name) {
  alert(name)
}

function User() {
  return function(){
    Name(name);
  }
}

function callName() {
  Name(name);
}

callName();

// but it alert nothing
```

Comment: yes .Because `name` is undefined .Check your console.log

Comment: so how can we solve this because whenever i try to invoke callName() it is not working even if we do this callName("Alice") but is is also not working

Answer (score 3):

> Yes its not working

Because `name` not defined in you dom .if you need  alert.You should pass the variable from `callName(prop)` Like below

```js
function Name(prop) {
  alert(prop)
}

function User() {  // useless function
  return function(){
    Name(name);
  }
}

function callName(prop) {
  Name(prop);
}

callName('Alice');
```

Comment: check the snippet its working .. What you mean by not working ?